# Jasmine or Mocha wrapper in Lightning Testing Service does not provide actual code coverage. How to measure JavaScript code coverage?

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, salesforcedx, lightning-testing-service, jasmine

I have to test JavaScript code in lightning components with % code coverage.

Lightning testing service report does not include code coverage information.

Is there any way to measure JavaScript code coverage in lightning components?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. We can generate code coverage report using sfdx-coverage plugin. You can get it from [here](https://github.com/aheber/sfdx-coverage).

This is code coverage report.
[image: Result]
For more details please refer to my question on trailblazer community from  [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000lQkDQAU)